# How do I prefix a controller with the user name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am having some problems with the new routing in Rails 3. What is the best way to prefix the path with a user name. Right now I have the following code:

```
resources :links, :path => '/:username' do
  put 'star', :on => :member
end
```

But it leaves params empty.

EDIT:

I would like to have a urls like:

```
/:username/links  
/:username/links/:id/star
```

And I would like to be able to fetch params[:username]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `scope` for this, it's much neater:

```
 scope :path => ":username" do
   resources :links do
     put 'star', :on => :member
   end
 end
```

Comment: This looks promising, but when I am trying to fetch params[:username] I get nil.

Comment: @magnushjelm: This is actually working for me, I don't know why yours would be nil: https://gist.github.com/516d3dd3989dffe9ded5

Comment: It's very strange. When I am testing this in the console it seems to work. When I test in the browser the params sometimes shows up with a delay of one request. I am upgrading an app from 2.3.9 to 3.0.3 so my code is most likely broken elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

you should user nested resources

```
resources :users do
  resources :links do
    put 'star', :on=>:member
  end
end
```

then, if you implement to_param in user.rb

```
def to_param
  username.parameterize
end
```

Then you'll have

```
/:username/links
/:username/links/23
/:username/links/23/star
```

Comment: I would like to have /:username/links but doesn't this give me: /users/:username/links?

Comment: Yes, that gives him /users/:username. He wants it without the /users/ prefix.